# Set style zoom level openlayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

In Openlayers it was possible to turn certain features on or off depending on the zoom level.  I have not found the same functionality in OpenLayers 3 despite looking through the documentation.  Does anyone know how to do this?  This is the feature I'm placing on the map and `ol.style.Text` is what I would like to display only after the user is zoomed in to a particular zoom level.

```
var geoJsonObj = {
  'type': 'Feature',
  'geometry': JSON.parse(response.FieldList[key].Shape)
}
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geoJsonObj)
});
Fields[Field.FieldID] = new ol.layer.Vector({
  projection: 'EPSG:4269',
  source: vectorSource,
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'yellow',
      width: 1
    }),
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: rcisWebMapUtilities.convertHex(response.FieldList[key].Shade, '0.5')
    }),
    text: new ol.style.Text({
      textAlign: 'Center',
      text: response.FieldList[key].Acres,
      scale: 1
    })
  })
});
```

Comment: does `minResolution` , `maxResolution` on vector layer initialization fit your needs???? api doc here --> http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.layer.Vector.html

Comment: Not really because the Style is part of the layer so not just the text is hidden the entire layer gets hidden...

Comment: then you may use the `ol.style.StyleFunction() ` instead of a static style. It accepts two params `ol.Feature` and `resolution`. So using the resolution return your static style with or without text. If you need further help I ll try to make a fiddle.

Comment: If you would make a fiddle I would appreciate it, I have looked at numerous examples and they all seem to be different...and when I try to use many of them i receive "function does not exist" error's

Comment: ...when I try to use "ol.style.styleFunction" I get the error "ol.style.styleFunction is not a constructor" and I've also tried the other naming convention "ol.style.StyleFunction" with the same result

Comment: just pass a simple function that returns an `ol.style`. e.g `style: function(feature,resolution){return new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'yellow',
      width: 1
    }),
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: rcisWebMapUtilities.convertHex(response.FieldList[key].Shade, '0.5')
    }),
    text: new ol.style.Text({
      textAlign: 'Center',
      text: response.FieldList[key].Acres,
      scale: 1
    })
  })}`

Comment: and here is a fiddle-->http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/c1abw8jy/ which uses a style function. Its not your case but you may get the idea

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The vector layer example demonstrates the use of a style function for resolution dependent styling: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-layer.html

Here is a simplified version:

```
var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector(),
  style: function(feature, resolution) {
    var text = resolution < 5000 ? feature.get('name') : '';
    return new ol.style.Style({
      text: new ol.style.Text({
        text: text,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
          color: '#000'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
          color: '#f00',
          width: 3
        })
      })
    });
  }
});
```

The layer above would render feature `name`s at resolutions below 5000 map units per pixel.

The vector layer example above has some additional code to reuse styles when possible.  If you've got a ton of features, you can put excess pressure on the garbage collector by creating new style instances for every render frame.

Comment: Thanks Tim!!!  this is exactly what I needed!!  Can I add multiple styles like this to a layer?  For example I want the "Fill" style to be constant but the "Text" style to behave the way it does above.

Comment: @user3557112 - the style function can return a single `ol.style.Style` object or an array of the same.  In a single style object, you can have both a text and a fill symbolizer (just add a `fill` property to the `ol.style.Style` object above).  You would only need to return multiple style objects if you wanted multiple strokes, different rendering geometries, z-index control, or something similar.  So start off by just adding a `fill` to the single style object above.

Comment: Yes, I understand this and the "Fill" is only active under the condition of resolution being less than 5000 and I need it to be constant.  I tried adding an additional style in an array [ ] of styles without a condition but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with to show labels but keep a constant style underneath...

```
 style: function (feature, resolution) {
                            var text = resolution * 100000 < 10 ? response.FieldList[key].Acres : '';

                            if (text != "") {
                                styleCache[text] = [new ol.style.Style({
                                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                        color: '#319FD3',
                                        width: 1
                                    }),
                                    text: new ol.style.Text({
                                        font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
                                        text: text,
                                        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                            color: '#000'
                                        }),
                                        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                                            color: '#fff',
                                            width: 3
                                        })
                                    }),
                                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                        color: rcisWebMapUtilities.convertHex(response.FieldList[key].Shade, '0.5')
                                    })
                                })];
                            }
                            else if (text == "") {
                                styleCache[text] = [new ol.style.Style({
                                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                                        color: rcisWebMapUtilities.convertHex(response.FieldList[key].Shade, '0.5')
                                    })
                                })
                                ]
                            } return styleCache[text];
                        }
```