# Listening to zoom-level change

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I need to add some text to the map when zoom level is > 15 and remove the text when zoom level is < 15. How do I go about listening to changes in zoom level? I tried 'change:resolution' event, but it didn't work, so I'm out of ideas.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37873359/7707749 might give you a better idea. If you want us to provide of better help, please input your code into the question, thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks, it solves my problem.

Comment: No problem and glad I was able to help you out :)